# What is wrong whit this jQuery submit function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, submit

This code runs smoothly except submit function. If I change the submit function with another function such as "show();" it works. Why doesn't it run this submit function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    email = $.trim(email);
    var password = $('#password').val();
    password = $.trim(password);

    if (email == "" || password == "") {
      $('.division').show();
    } else {
      $('#form').submit();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" action="run.php">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="keep" value="yes">
  <label for="keep">Keep login</label>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Sign in" onClick="return false;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you've given your submit button the `id` `"submit"`. Browsers add elements to the `form` object using the `id`, so the normal `submit` function of the form is being replaced with a reference to your submit button.

Change the name (and probably `id`) of the submit button to (say) `submit-btn` and it will work. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/gikil/1/)

Separately from that, though, I wouldn't hook `click` on the submit button at all; I'd hook submit on the form element, since forms can be submitted in other ways (pressing Enter in certain form fields, for instance).

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/gikil/2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#form').submit(function(e){
          var email = $('#email').val();
          email = $.trim(email);
          var password = $('#password').val();
          password = $.trim(password);

          if( email == "" || password == "") {
            $('.division').show();
            e.preventDefault(); // Don't allow the form submission
          }else{
            $('#form').submit();
          }
        })
      });
    </script>
    <!-- Using GET rather than POST, and no action
    attribute, so that it posts back to the jsbin page -->
    <form id="form" method="get">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password"> 
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="keep" value="yes">
      <label for="keep">Keep login</label>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    </form>
    <div class="division" style="display: none">Please fill in an email and password</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have changed the id and it has totally worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nijamitsu: You're welcome. This is one of those awful side-effect things. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your input element, you have `onClick="return false;"`This onClick function is being given priority over the click handler that you defined in jQuery. If you remove the onClick portion of your input element, your jQuery code will run.

Aside, there is a problem with your submit code in that it never actually prevents the POST to the server. See my edit below:

```
            if( email == "" || password == "") {
                $('.division').show();
                return false;
            }else{
                ('#form').submit();
            }
```

You must explicitly return false to prevent the form from submitting to the server. Alternatively, you can just remove the else clause altogether, due to the fact that if the function doesn't explicitly return false, it will complete and continue with the form submission.

Also note that for form submissions, it is typically better to use the onSubmit event as opposed to the onClick event, since forms can technically be submitted by hitting the 'enter' key as well as clicking the submit button. When onClick is used, the submission is not triggered via hitting the enter key.